# Java Split regex

Tags: java, regex, split

> Given a string S, find the number of words in that string. For this problem a word is defined by a string of one or more English letters.
>
> Note: Space or any of the special characters like ![,?.\_'@+] will act as a delimiter.
>
> Input Format: The string will only contain lower case English letters, upper case English letters, spaces, and these special characters: ![,?._'@+].
>
> Output Format: On the first line, print the number of words in the string. The words don't need to be unique. Then, print each word in a separate line.

My code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    String regex = "( |!|[|,|?|.|_|'|@|+|]|\\\\)+";
    String[] arr = str.split(regex);
    
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

When I submit the code, it works for just over half of the test cases. I do not know what the test cases are. I'm asking for help with the Murphy's law. What are the situations where the regex I implemented won't work?

Comment: Why are you including a backslash in your regex? It's not in the requirement. Also, you're using `[` and `]` without escaping them.

Comment: For characters with special meaning in regex, you need to escape them. As a side note, you might find it easier and clearer to split based off of a character set (for example, `[a-z]` is the set of all lowercase letters) rather than a series of X or Y or Z cases.

Comment: I apologize. Didn't know I had to escape the backslash in order to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't escape some special characters in your regex. Let's start with `[]`. Since you don't escape them, the part `[|,|?|.|_|'|@|+|]` is treated like a set of characters `|,?._'@+`. This means that your regex doesn't split on `[` and `]`.

For example `x..]y+[z` is split to `x`, `]y` and `[z`.

You can fix that by escaping those characters. That will force you to escape more of them and you end up with a proper definition:

```
String regex = "( |!|\\[|,|\\?|\\.|_|'|@|\\+|\\])+";
```

Note that instead of defining alternatives, you could use a set which will make your regex easier to read:

```
String regex = "[!\\[,?._'@+\\].]+";
```

In this case you only need to escape `[` and `]`.

UPDATE:

There's also a problem with leading special character (like in your example `".Hi?there[broski.]@@@@@"`). You need to split on it but it produces an empty string in the results. I don't think there's a way to use split function without producing it but you can mitigate it by removing the first group before splitting using the same regex:

```
String[] arr = str.replaceFirst(regex, "").split(regex);
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. I did a test input of ".Hi?there[broski.]@@@@@" without the quotes. The output printed out 4, a blank line, hi, there, broski (each on there own line). I assume it printed out the blank line because of the '.' in front of "Hi". How would I fix that?